# pygame screen.fill command has undefined error

Tags: python, pygame, background

It looks like in pygame, screen command, like in screen.fill() is not in pygame. How do I set the background color?

Here is the code if needed:

```
pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

`screen` is not a built-in variable. It seems that in your case `screen` should be the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object associated with the display. This `pygame.Surface` is returned when the Pygame window is created with [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode):

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])
```

The other option is to get the display *Surface* with [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface)

```py
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```